# Binding Dropdown with large dataset Angular 2

Tags: angular, dropdown

I am trying to bind Angular drop-down (Angular 2+) with 19000+ records, it's hanging application, we are unable to perform any other operation post that.

I am just using `*ngFor`, for same

```
 <select class="form-control" name="occupation" 
     [(ngModel)]="model.occupation" #occupation="ngModel" required 
     (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
     <option *ngFor="let c of ocupencycollection;">
        {{ c }}
     </option>
 </select>
```

Any other feasible solution?

Comment: dropdown with 19000+ records? omg!

Comment: Sad but true it's client requirement need all occupations list ):

Comment: Change your UI. Use a typeahead, or a simple search box.

Comment: use a dropdown with scroll ( use pagination ) or autocomplete typehead

Comment: May be using checkboxes or radio buttons and pagination would be better. 
Maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that without seriously performance hit. 
I would suggest a commercial solution. I am using Kendo-UI for Angular.
In my case I allow user to select partner (5 million records) in DropDownList. I displayed 20 partners and then allow filtering.

Appropriate demo for your problem would be:

- [Remote binding](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/data-binding/#toc-binding-to-remote-data)
- [Filtering](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/filtering/)

You can combine both approaches. There is also a request to support endless scrolling, which may be the best approach.

If payed solution is not acceptable, you can load items on demand. First you show 20 items, and then after user scroll to the end, you load another page of records. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302989/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-add-items-on-scrolling) may help you.

Comment: Kendo is again a cost so unable to use that :)

Comment: I think then your only solution is to create custom component, which will listen for scroll event and load new items when scroll to end. This way you will have custom implementation of endless/infinite scrolling.

Comment: @Makla
I can fix it for selection but how to handle that for edit scenario? Because in edit form to show selected dropdown value we need to have all the data available. How would you handle that scenario?